# php auth user redirect header location

Tags: php, authentication

This worked for me for a long time and suddenly it stopped working.
I have a .htaccess and .htpasswd in the same folder (users) and below is the index.php file

```
<?
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) { 
header("Location: http://website.com/users/".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); 
    } 
else header("Location: http://website.com/failed_login"); 
?>
```

Comment: could you be more precise in what stopped working?

Comment: what error it gave you..?

Comment: It still ask for the user and password - However it redirects to http://website.com/failed_login if I click cancel or if I input the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) { 
   header("Location: http://website.com/users/".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); 
} 
else {
   header("Location: http://website.com/failed_login");
} 
?>
```

Comment: You should write comment about what you changed in the code when you post answer by copying the code from question.